# How to tell how long each user visits each page?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, web, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a good way to tell how long a given user spends on a given page of a web application, with an accuracy of about one minute?

One solution that occurred to me would be to use Javascript to hit a web service every minute, and keep track of the hits in a database.  But I was wondering if there was a better way... Would there be a way to accomplish this through Google Analytics?  If so, how?

Comment: I imagine such a metric wouldn't come from the page itself, but from the comparison (which can be done entirely server-side) of when the page was requested vs. when the next page was requested.  (Assuming that if no subsequent page is requested then it's an abandoned session.)

Comment: Google Analytics might be the way to go. In page analytics in particular

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingTiming

Answer (score 3):

First, I agree with the comments regarding analytics software and you should definitely look into them for things of this nature.

I don't know how well this would work and I definitely don't believe it's the best way to go, but if you're dead set on doing this client side you could perhaps try something like:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    alert( parseInt(end - start, 10)/60000 + " minutes" );
};
```

The idea here is to save the current time once a user visits your page. Once they navigate away, the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload) event should fire and run the function to calculate the time they've spent on the page. I imagine you could add in <s>an ajax call (or something)</s> a **synchronous call** to save the total time somewhere.

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2a2fK/3/)

*Note*: jsfiddle will block these events, but you can still see the output in the error log by opening up the console. Just hit `Run` to fire the event once you have the console open.

**EDIT**:

Please see @Ian's comments below on using an AJAX request inside of the `onbeforeunload` event.

Comment: AJAX requests in the `beforeunload` event aren't cross-browser consistent, and the best/only way to help them are with **synchronous** requests. When a page is left, browsers abort open AJAX requests. So when you initiate one in the `beforeunload` event, which is right before the `unload` event, there's a good chance that the request doesn't make it far enough in its lifecycle to reach the server

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Ian, like I said above...I wasn't too sure how well it would work. You're completely correct though, they would need to be synchronous.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to explain what might happen :) To me, something like what the OP is asking for only requires communication to the server. The server shouldn't have to respond. So if the AJAX request can leave the browser by the time it's aborted by the browser (which just means the browser won't process its response), then that should be plenty fine. In a project I've worked on, we sent an AJAX request in `beforeunload`, and we needed it to be synchronous. Something that might help is to put a timeout on it (we did for 1000ms) like jQuery `$.ajax` allows.

Comment: And sorry for the wording - it'll still be an AJAX request, but be a synchronous one (third parameter in the `.open` method will be `false`)

Comment: I've actually never been in a situation where I've needed to use either inside of an `onbeforeunload` event, so the entire idea was a bit speculation at first as I've not actually tested it. Again, I greatly appreciate you pointing it out! I'll add a little comment in the post to see your comments.

Comment: Thanks for this - if I had gone the clientside route, I would have done recurring pings in happy ignorance. I wasn't even aware that there was any such event... It just seemed like it would be too prone to abuse.

Comment: @Eric - You're very welcome and I completely understand you deciding against this route. I just wanted to lay it out as an option in the event you needed it.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I've put some work into a small JavaScript library and service that times how long a user interacts with a web page.  It actually does exactly what Chase describes in his/her answer!  However, it has the added benefit of more accurately (not perfectly, though) tracking how long a user is actually interacting with the page.  It ignore times that a user switches to different tabs, goes idle, minimizes the browser, etc.

Edit: I have updated the example to include the current API usage.

http://timemejs.com

An example of its usage:

**Include in your page:**

```
<script src="http://timemejs.com/timeme.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
TimeMe.initialize({
    currentPageName: "home-page", // page name
    idleTimeoutInSeconds: 15 // time before user considered idle
});
</script>
```

**If you want to report the times yourself to your backend:**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","ENTER_URL_HERE", false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var timeSpentOnPage = TimeMe.getTimeOnCurrentPageInSeconds();
    xmlhttp.send(timeSpentOnPage);
});
```

TimeMe.js also supports sending timing data via websockets, so you don't have to try to force a full synchronous http request into the `document.onbeforeunload` event.